PySide snipping tool coordinates mismatch due to monitor scaling and dual monitor setup
I have a Python application that captures a region of the screen using PySide6 and PIL libraries.
The application works well on 1980x1080 resolution monitor. However, when using it on my primary monitor with a resolution 2560x1600 and a scaling factor of 175%, there is a significant mismatch between the captured region and the actual screenshot.
I suspect this discrepancy is due to the monitor scaling factor affecting coordinates calculations. How can I adjust the coordinates to account for the monitor scaling factor?
Additionally, I would like to extend the screen capture functionally to work on dual monitors, capturing regions from both monitors simultaneously. What approach should I take to implement this feature?
# source from https://github.com/harupy/snipping-tool
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pygetwindow as gw

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        root = tk.Tk()
        screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
        root.withdraw()  # Hide the root window
        screen_geometry = gw.getWindowsWithTitle(gw.getActiveWindow().title)[0]
        virtual_screen_width = screen_geometry.width
        virtual_screen_height = screen_geometry.height
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, virtual_screen_width, virtual_screen_height)
        self.setWindowTitle(' ')
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.3)
        self.num_snip = 0
        self.is_snipping = False
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(
            QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        )
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        print('Capture the screen...')
        print('Press q if you want to quit...')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.is_snipping:
            brush_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)
            lw = 0
            opacity = 0
        else:
            brush_color = (128, 128, 255, 128)
            lw = 3
            opacity = 0.3

        self.setWindowOpacity(opacity)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('black'), lw))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(*brush_color))
        qp.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.begin, self.end))

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Q:
            print('Quit')
            self.close()
        event.accept()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.position()
        self.end = self.begin
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.position()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.num_snip += 1
        x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())

        self.is_snipping = True
        self.repaint()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        self.is_snipping = False
        self.repaint()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        img_name = 'snip{}.png'.format(self.num_snip)
        img.save(img_name)
        print(img_name, 'saved')
        img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I am currently exploring the screeninfo library to address issues related to screen resolution and DPI scaling..

You should read the QScreen, QPaintDevice (from which QWidget inherits) and the DPI related documentation.

Focus on a single specific problem, do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. Anyway, see High DPI.

Just a little bit math:
img = ImageGrab.grab()
# crop with correct scale
screen_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
x1 = x1 / screen_width * img.width
x2 = x2 / screen_width * img.width
y1 = y1 / screen_height * img.height
y2 = y2 / screen_height * img.height
img = img.crop(box=(x1, y1, x2, y2))

In addition, don't use bbox because it will reduce the quality. Use img.crop() instead.
Btw your code is not usable on mac. But I have a cross platform version of a snipping tool, SideDragScreenshot.py:
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide6.QtGui import QScreen, QPixmap
import sys

using_debug_mode = None

class DraggingPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, callback=None, cancel_callback=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.callback = callback
        self.cancel_callback = cancel_callback
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None
        self.rect:QtCore.QRect = None
        
        window_tools.set_frameless(self)
        window_tools.set_bg_to_almost_transparent(self)

        height = screen.height()
        width = screen.width()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.rect:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.Qt.white, 2))
            painter.drawRect(self.rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.start_x = event.globalPosition().x()
            self.start_y = event.globalPosition().y()
            self.rect = QtCore.QRect(self.start_x, self.start_y, 0, 0)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.rect.setBottomRight(event.globalPosition().toPoint())
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.capture_screen()

    def capture_screen(self):
        xs = [self.rect.x(), self.rect.x() + self.rect.width()]
        ys = [self.rect.y(), self.rect.y() + self.rect.height()]
        xs.sort()
        ys.sort()
        x1, x2 = xs
        y1, y2 = ys
        w = x2-x1
        h = y2-y1
        self.hide()

        if self.rect and w > 0 and h > 0:
            def do_capture():
                screen_cap = QScreen.grabWindow(QApplication.primaryScreen(), 0, 0, 
                                                screen.width(),
                                                screen.height())
                to_img_scale_x = lambda val: round(val * screen_cap.width()/screen.width())
                to_img_scale_y = lambda val: round(val * screen_cap.height()/screen.height())
                screen_cap = screen_cap.copy(to_img_scale_x(x1),
                                                to_img_scale_y(y1),
                                                to_img_scale_x(w),
                                                to_img_scale_y(h)) if True else screen_cap
                if using_debug_mode: print("Screenshot taken!")
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda: self.callback(screen_cap) and self.deleteLater())
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, do_capture)
        else:
            if using_debug_mode: print("Screenshot canceled!")
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, lambda: self.cancel_callback() and self.deleteLater())

        





### Tools ###

class window_tools:
    @staticmethod
    def set_flag(widget:QWidget, flag: QtCore.Qt, on=True):
        # Get current flags and remove the FramelessWindowHint flag
        if on:
            widget.setWindowFlags(flag)
        else:
            all_flags = widget.windowFlags()
            widget.setWindowFlags(all_flags & ~flag)
    @staticmethod
    def set_no_entity_mode(widget:QWidget, transparent_no_enitity=True, frameless = True):
        "the mouse can click behind the window."
        window_tools.set_flag(widget, QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint, on=frameless)
        widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, on=transparent_no_enitity)
    def set_bg_to_almost_transparent(widget):
        "Opacity: 1/255, Clickable\n\n`widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #01000000;')`"
        widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #01000000;')
    @staticmethod
    def set_frameless(widget, on = True):
        window_tools.set_flag(widget, QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint, on=on)
    @staticmethod
    def set_always_on_top(widget, on = True):
        window_tools.set_flag(widget, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, on=on)
    @staticmethod
    def create_window(title="", borderless=False, always_on_top=False, width=300, height=300):
        # Create a new QWidget (or QMainWindow)
        new_window = QWidget()
        new_window.setWindowTitle(title)
        
        # Set window flags based on parameters
        if borderless:
            new_window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        if always_on_top:
            new_window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        
        # Set the size of the window
        new_window.resize(width, height)
        
        return new_window

class screen:
    @staticmethod
    def size():
        return app_using.primaryScreen().size()
    @staticmethod
    def width():
        return screen.size().width()
    @staticmethod
    def height():
        return screen.size().height()
    

### main function ###

app_using: QApplication = None
def launch_screenshot_panel(Qapp: QApplication, on_screenshot=None, on_cancel=None, debug_logging=False):
    "Please STORE the returned widget to prevent garbage collection"
    global using_debug_mode, app_using
    using_debug_mode = debug_logging
    app_using = Qapp
    panel = DraggingPanel(on_screenshot, on_cancel)
    panel.show()
    return panel
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    
    def on_screenshot(img: QPixmap):
        img.save("a.png")
        quit()
    def on_screenshot_cancelled():
        print("cancelled callback!")
    panel = launch_screenshot_panel(app, on_screenshot=on_screenshot, on_cancel=on_screenshot_cancelled, debug_logging=True)

    sys.exit(app_using.exec())
    

